# How to convert a string into an array of integers, containing the ascii values of their corresponding characters?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string into an list in f#, for my encryption algorithm. How would i solve this problem?

I know that (int char) returns the ascii value of the character, but i don't know how to map a whole string to an list of integers. As far as i know, there isn't a built in cast for string to list, or a mapping function that takes in a string and maps it to an list.

Answer (score 3):

```
let toAsciiVals (s:string) = Array.map int (s.ToCharArray())
```

Example in FSI:

```
> toAsciiVals "abcd";;
val it : int [] = [|97; 98; 99; 100|]
```

Comment: You don't need `s.ToCharArray()`: `Seq.map int s` because a string is a sequence of char itself.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are sequences of characters, so you can just map the conversion function over them:

```
"test" |> Seq.map int;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [116; 101; 115; 116]
```

If you really need an array and not a sequence you can tack another `|> Seq.toArray` onto the end.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are actually trying to do is to encrypt a unicode string, then you can use the .NET functions for converting the strings to and from byte arrays, whether UTF8 or UTF32. UTF8 is more memory efficient as bytes, but if you must store the chars as ints one to one, then going through UTF32 will result in less ints. Note that using ASCII encoding will not preserve unicode characters.

```
open System.Text

let s = "abc æøå ÆØÅ"

let asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes s
let asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString asciiBytes
printfn "%s" asciiString // outputs "abc ??? ???"

let utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes s
let utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString utf8Bytes
printfn "%s" utf8String // outputs "abc æøå ÆØÅ"

let utf32Bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes s
let utf32String = Encoding.UTF32.GetString utf32Bytes
printfn "%s" utf32String // outputs "abc æøå ÆØÅ"

let bytesToInts (bytes: byte[]) = bytes |> Array.map (fun b -> int b)

let intsAsBytesToInts (bytes: byte[]) =
    bytes |> Array.chunkBySize 4 |> Array.map (fun b4 -> BitConverter.ToInt32(b4,0))

let utf8Ints = bytesToInts utf8Bytes
printfn "%A" utf8Ints
// [|97; 98; 99; 32; 195; 166; 195; 184; 195; 165; 32; 195; 134; 195; 152; 195; 133|]
// Note: This reflects what the encoded UTF8 byte array looks like.

let utf32Ints = intsAsBytesToInts utf32Bytes
printfn "%A" utf32Ints
// [|97; 98; 99; 32; 230; 248; 229; 32; 198; 216; 197|]
// Note: This directly reflects the chars in the unicode string.
```

Comment: I am not sure whether or not UTF32 is a one-to-one mapping of unicode chars to 32-bit values. I studied this some years ago, and suspect that there are some exotic chars in some cultures that use some sort of escape mechanism. If that's correct, then all the more reason to use Encoding rather than make your own mappings.

Comment: I overlooked that there is also Encoding.Unicode, which uses UTF-16. Whether or not this uses escape codes, and if so, for what chars and languages, I don't know.